# How to allow limited access to Dropdowns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-protection

I work in an office. We use Google Sheets. I designed a sheet with three dropdowns to allow people to change info filtered by those three dropdowns.

I am the editor, and so are two other people.

I protected the entire sheet, with the exception of those three dropdown cells.

I allow anyone with the link to view the sheet, and we sent it out to multiple people.

This all seemed to work well until today.

Now people, who could before, use the dropdowns to change the data on the page are no longer able to do so.

I removed the protection, and reenabled it.  Didn't help. I even removed protection to the entire sheet - no results there either.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you are sharing the spreadsheet with multiple people as *view only*. That means that those people do not have edit access to any part of the spreadsheet. The protections you have set to the dropdowns make no difference to them.

To make it work, you will have to share the spreadsheet as "anyone with link can *edit*", and use sheet protections to make the spreadsheet read-only, applying "except certain cells" in the sheet with the dropdowns.

Alternatively, encourage the view-only users to apply [filter views](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) to choose which rows to show directly in the data sheet. Filter views are different from regular filters.

For additional ease of use, you can insert links in the frozen section of the sheet to easily switch between filter views, instead of having to go to **Data > Filter views** to switch. See the [Filter views example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME5b4J6fQa8RRainxGtQkwTKFCg96N8_k6kCe8ABNyk/edit#gid=2048818001&fvid=336145647) spreadsheet for an illustration.